# How does the plain: hash work in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone tell me what is `plain:` hash here?.

```
def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end
```

I got this json here below as output. How did the `plain:` hash works?.

```
{"title"=>"First article!", "text"=>"This is my first article."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

> 2.2.7 Rendering Text
>
> You can send plain text - with no markup at all - back to the browser
>   by using the :plain option to render.

So you just get back exactly the result from the `.inspect` method on the hash with no further formatting.